# How to reduce the time to switch node connection (in cluster) when a node is down

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a rabbitmq cluster with many nodes and queue mirroring.
It works in environment with unstable network connection (that is why we use clustering). 
When the currently using node is down - we have to wait few seconds before masstransit will switch to the other node.

How can we optimize it?
Does masstransit use "rabbitmqctl cluster_status" to check which nodes are running? Or mayby is it trying given node addresses one by one?
Can we change a timeout value which is used to determine by masstransit if node is alive?
Or maybe can we change something in rabbitmq config? For example "net_ticktime" in advanced config.

---- update ----

I found 2 options:

1. Heartbeat (but setting it to 4s didn't change anything)
2. Change RabbitMqClient ConnectionFactory.RequestedConnectionTimeout settings. But MassTransit doesn't give us an option to override it...

Comment: I added the `RequestedConnectionTimeout` configuration setting to MassTransit, so that the connection timeout could be lowered. Will be in v6.